# Padding not working properly for the body element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give my self some extra space to work with at the bottom of the site by adding `bottom-padding: 50px;` to the body in CSS but for some reason it does not add anything. I've seen people do this to make the page to a scrollable length but for me it literally does nothing no matter what.

This is the code so far:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}


.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.nav-item a {
  font-family: poppins, arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav-item:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.project-button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #86c232;
}

.projects-link {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href=""><strong> Tiam Nazari </strong></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <button class="project-button">
              <a class="projects-link" href="">Projects</a>
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `padding` is working, you just don't have any content. `Height` controls the actual height of the element (basically the distance from the outermost edges of the container) whereas `padding` controls the distance between the content and the edges.

If you want space, add a static `height` and then remove it once all of your content is in. If you still want white space vertically or horizontally once the content is in, then use `padding`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

section.first {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: orange;
  padding-top: 4em;
}

section:not(.first) {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 600px;
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.nav-item a {
  font-family: poppins, arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav-item:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.project-button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #86c232;
}

.projects-link {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href=""><strong> Tiam Nazari </strong></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="project-button">
              <a class="projects-link" href="">Projects</a>
            </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="first">section 1</section>
  <section>section 2</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. Use `background-color: red;` to see how the body grows. Make sure you're connecting the documents correctly.

Comment: True, other options would be either to add more content inside your body but below the header or use height: 1000px; in your body, be sure to use background-color: some-color; to see the changes